# How can I rotate a UIViewController to its supported interface orientation when navigating to it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, ios9

I have a viewcontroller (with child viewcontrollers) that is locked in portrait, using the following code to accomplish this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([self.centerViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.centerViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

This works perfectly, I can "override" the supportedInterfaceOrientations in my current centerViewController if I need to lock that view, and leave it out if I want the view to support everything.

The problem is that the views that are locked don't rotate to their supported orientation upon navigation. One view is locked in portrait, but when showing another view in landscape and navigating to this one shows it in landscape, even though landscape is not supported for this view.

How can I make sure the view is rotated to an allowed orientation upon navigating?

Answer (score 0):

I will get rotated automatically if you have returned your supported orientation in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

```
#pragma mark - Orientation Handling
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {// iOS 6 autorotation fix
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {// iOS 6 autorotation fix
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {// iOS 6 autorotation fix
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have returned my supported orientation in supportedInterfaceOrientations, but the view is not automatically rotated when navigating to it from another view that is in another orientation.

Comment: I have just tried above code in my application, give it a try.

Comment: I think it's because I don't actually navigate. I have a mainViewController which has a childViewController. The child is removed upon navigating and is replaced by the new child view controller. The main view controller's lifecycle methods aren't fired this way. Can I somehow force them to?

Comment: No.. I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add following property in `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (readwrite) BOOL restrictRotation;
```

Add following code in `AppDelegate.m`

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(self.restrictRotation)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Add following code in ViewController.m which you want to restrict orientation:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //  (iOS 6)
    //  Prefer (force) landscape
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Also when you leaving from your Landscape ViewController.m make following function call

```
[self restrictRotation:NO];
```

Hopefully i solves your problem.