# ObjC disable ViewController rotation

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to disable screen rotation in just one ViewController. I'm using this to change screen orientation to portrait:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

and I'm disabling rotation like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return navigationController.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

but it's not working. It rotates screen to portrait but it does't lock it, if I turn device it changes screen orientation.

Comment: Please visit my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655338/how-can-i-rotate-a-uiviewcontroller-to-its-supported-interface-orientation-when/34655782#34655782)

Comment: You could be missing out something, i have tested this code, its working fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

The above code will only work with UIViewControllers not UINavigationController stacks. If you are using a UINavigationController you should do the following:

Solution 1:

1. Add to `AppDelegate.h` a variable: `@property (nonatomic , assign) bool blockRotation;`
2. Add to `AppDelegate.m` function:

   ```
   - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application       supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
       if (self.blockRotation) {
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
   ```
3. In controller want disable add this code:

   ```
   #import "AppDelegate.h"
   //Put to `viewDidload`
   AppDelegate* shared=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   shared.blockRotation=YES;
   ```

Solution 2: you can follow this answer:  [Hanling orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780925/handling-rotation-in-ios6/12780927#12780927)

Comment: Doesn't work, maybe because that I'm using auto layout it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to temporarily disable automatic rotation, avoid manipulating the orientation masks to do this. Instead, override the shouldAutorotate method on the initial view controller. This method is called before performing any autorotation. If it returns NO, then the rotation is suppressed.

So you need to subclass 'UINavigationController', implement shouldAutorotate and use your navigation controller class in your storyboard.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    id currentViewController = self.topViewController;

    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```